# Submitting forms in thyeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf , trying to submit a form while reading msisdn as input

```
<form th:action="@{/getMsisdn}" th:object="${mymodelobject}">
 <input name="msisdn" type="text" th:value="*{msisdn}">Msisdn</input>
 </form>
```

At the Controller end

```
 @RequestMapping("/getMsisdn")
   public void getMsisdn(@RequestParam(name = "msisdn") String msisdn, 
   HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Reached in msisdn"+msisdn);

    session.setAttribute(Constants.MSISDN, msisdn);
    res.sendRedirect(Constants.EXTERNALCG);

   }
```

Error i am getting : Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "msisdn"

Comment: Nevermind , i got the answer , for single attribute i can do like this  <form action="#" th:action="@{/getMsisdn}"  method="post">
         <input type="text" name="msisdn"/>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

For single attribute i can do like this , thanks

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/getMsisdn}"  method="post">
     <input type="text" name="msisdn"/>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```